# How to save PendingIntent parameters (context,requestcode,intent,flag) in sqlite database, and retrieve it

Tags: android, sqlite, action, android-pendingintent

How to save PendingIntent parameters (context,requestcode,intent,flag) in sqlite database, and retrieve these parameter from database and build it.
Then this parameter working will same as a pendingintent.
   I want to save Action permanently in sqlite database.

Comment: You cannot save intent and context inside the SQLite database.

Comment: Then what is another option to save parameters of pendingintent,  like a get package name, get Class name and other field in string from intent and save this, is this possible?

Comment: You can try that. But, why do you need to save the PendingIntents?

Comment: I am doing one project. in that i will save action permanently, pendingintent is parameter of action, thats why pendingintent parameters are  extract and save into database, then retrieve from database and build as it is.

Comment: Ok. Was just curious to know the concept, so asked you. Yes you can try saving separate parameters for PendingIntent in the SQLite database. Hope it helps you and all the best for your project.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Of course the code that is creating the `PendingIntent` by calling `PendingIntent.getActivity()` or whatever could save the parameters in a database. You can't save the `Context`, but you can save the rest of the parameters as they are primitives or implement `Parcelable` (ie : you can serialize them to a byte array). If you are, however, askling, if another chunk of code can extract the parameters from a `PendingIntent`, the answer is no.

Comment: Hello David,                                                                                                 You are Correct, I want to save action permanently.  Please write a answer how to save pendingIntent parameters(without context) in database and retrieve it. and also build it.  without context, we will get context runtime. that not need to save.                                                    Thanks for Replay.